# Getting Sprite-kit update method delta time after breakpoints

Tags: sprite-kit, timedelta

I want to drive a fixed timestep physics engine from the SKScene

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
```

method.

This was perfectly functional in cocos2d, where the update method delivered a **delta** time, and where that delta time was stopped at breakpoints.

The sprite kit update method reports an absolute time, and when the debugger stops the next call will be made many seconds — or minutes — afterwards. Is there any nice solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a number of ways you can do this. My preferred method has always been to use a frame counter which updates by one every time the update method is called.

Another option is to save the time when the app delegate method `applicationWillResignActive` is called and again when the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method is called. You can subtract the time differential between the two.

Comment: Yea, but in the first case — counting frames — you don't get the real time behavior. And I guess that the second case — using AppDelegate methods — does not solve the issue with halting on breakpoints.

Comment: @FredrikJohansson - I included the second example as to illustrate keeping time in a real world scenario. As for counting frames, if you know you are running at, for example, 60 FPS you can extrapolate time spent.